# URL routing with codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, search

I have a controller named `search`. Codeigniter works in the following way if a user types `sitename.com/search` it hits the `search` controller and runs the `index` function.

If a user then types in `sitename.com/search/cars`, the controller will look for the function `cars` within the `search` controller.

However I want to have a generic function called lookup(), which takes the 2nd parameter in a URL string.

> For example:  sitename.com/search/**electronics** [electronics is
>   returned] sitename.com/search/**cheese** [cheese is returned]

Then it does a database lookup using the keyword if it finds a match it loads the page. In the case of cars it would be `sitename.com/search/cars` if no match then it redirects to `sitename.com/search/error`.

Is it possible to modify my controller to handle requests like this? Without specifying every possible route?

```
$route['Cars'] = 'sitename.com/search/Cars';  
$route['Cheese'] = 'sitename.com/search/Cheese';  
$route['Electronics'] = 'sitename.com/search/Electronics';
```

### Search Controller:

```
    <?php
    class Search extends CI_Controller {


     public function __construct()
           {
                parent::__construct();

        $this->load->helper('url');

//parse URL: run lookup() function then redirect to page if valid return


           }


        public function index()
        {
        //check for url string to see what set or collection to load:

        }

       public function lookup()
       {

       }


    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in route

```
$route['search/(:any)'] = "search/index/$1";
```

in controller

```
        public function index($value)
    {
        //$value = $1

    }
```

Comment: what happens when I don't have anything to pass to search/ and just want the default page won't it throw an error?

Comment: changed to `public function index($value = NULL)` works for default case now cheers.