# Codeigniter Routes having GET variables

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes

I am trying to use routes to redirect URL having GET variables as follows:

```
$route['^(beautified-link)'] = "controller/function?param=6";
```

But it is not considering it.. Please Suggest

Comment: try $route['^(beautified-link)'] = "controller/function/param/6";

Comment: maybe this help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22339178/url-routing-with-codeigniter/22339224#22339224

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i am not sure abot this but you could give a try by changing these values in the config file.

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = "PATH_INFO"; 
$config['enable_query_strings'] = TRUE;
```

and try accessing the url like

```
$this->input->get(‘param’);
```

Comment: @akhil.. that is in the case of function parameter.. bt in my case it is a GET variable that is usually called like: site.com/controller/function?param=6

Comment: @akhil.. Thanks a lot.. bt it didnt wrk :( i had to change my code to send the GET variable as a codeigniter function parameter and use routes as:`$route['^(beautified-link)'] = "controller/function/6";`

Answer (score 0):

```
$route['^(beautified-link)'] = "controller/function";
```

I think it can be done by only specifying controller and method, no need to maintain route for passing GET variable.

Answer (score 0):

why use get params?

autoload the url helper in config/autoload.php

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url');
```

and you could be able to use a url like

http://example.com/controller/function/param

param could be a number, a string or anything you want

in the controller you can read the param with this

```
$var=$this->uri->segment(3);
```

or

```
$var=$this->uri->segment(4);//depend of number of "/" that you put on the url
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to enable your query string in config file.

```
$config['enable_query_strings'] = TRUE;
```